# When to change the buffer size parameter of advertise function

Tags: ros, buffer, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow:[topic Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

I try to change the parameter of the advertise of buffer of size.

For example,I tried 1,200,1000,2000,...etc.

But I can't find their difference.

What are the cases of changing that parameter ?

Is there any sample code ?

Thank you !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37577/when-to-change-the--buffer-size--parameter-of---advertise-function/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will see the effect only under certain circumstances. First make sure you know what a buffer is used for, then you could try the following:

set the buffer size to 1 and publish 100 messages right after another by writing something like

> for (int i=0;i<100;++i)

> pub.publish(message);

This will publish the message 100 times but will most likely not be received that often. What happens is the following: If your code publishes a message, it will overwrite the last message which is still waiting in the buffer for transmission. How many messages will be received by the subscriber will depend on the network connection between the publisher and the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0